# Tecno Camon 15 pro stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, mediatek

My Tecno Camon 15 Pro is stuck in bootloop after I was trying to patch boot.img file.

### Phone Specs:

My phone's processor is MediaTek Helio P35 (MT6765) & it was running Android 10 build CD8-H655BCD-Q-GL-200708V314. Full phone specs [here](https://www.gsmarena.com/tecno_camon_15_pro-10094.php) if it helps. Bootloader of the phone is already unlocked.

### What did I do?

I downloaded ROOT.zip  for my phone from [HalabTech](https://support.halabtech.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=file&id=304824) and extracted boot img. I patched it and flashed it onto my phone.

### What phone's condition is?

It rebooted and since then it just getting rebooted again and again. It vibrates, shows Tecno logo for a few seconds and turns off. I cannot turn it off neither can I boot into recovery or fastboot. Its totally stuck and I get different errors from SP Flash Tool but not once which are as follows while trying to flash a ROM file I grabbed somewhere on the internet:

[image]
[image]

It does not have any other issues and I know it was the boot.img flashing which did this. So what should I do? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem on my Tecno Spark 3 a few months back. Unfortunately, despite the 100s of tutorials on how to flash a custom rom on Tecno phones, it's just not possible. What I remember doing is to flash the original files to the phone using the after_sales_service.exe tool. It still shows the bootloader unlocked message but at least the phone worked.

Comment: Try flashing using this tool: https://www.getdroidtips.com/download-tecno-flash-tool/

Comment: run a scan(on sp flash tool) and see if emmc is functional